# Trouble retrieving OEmbed object in Twitter4j

Tags: java, json, twitter4j, oembed

I am trying to get an OEmbed object from a Status object in Twitter4j then get the html to pass to a webpage. Right now I just have it in a main method for testing.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    ConfigurationBuilder cf = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    cf.setDebugEnabled(true)
        .setOAuthConsumerKey("")
        .setOAuthConsumerSecret("")
        .setOAuthAccessToken("")
        .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("")
        .setJSONStoreEnabled(true);

    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cf.build());
    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    Query query = new Query("hello world");
    query.setCount(5);

    try {
        QueryResult result = twitter.search(query); 
        List<Status> tweets = result.getTweets();
        String jsonString = TwitterObjectFactory.getRawJSON(tweets.get(0));
        System.out.println(jsonString);
        OEmbed embed = TwitterObjectFactory.createOEmbed(jsonString);
        System.out.println(embed.getHtml());
    } catch(TwitterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Credentials have been removed but they are correct in the program. The console output is below.

```
{"metadata":{"result_type":"recent","iso_language_code":"en"},"in_reply_to_status_id_str":null,"in_reply_to_status_id":null,"coordinates":null,"created_at":"Mon Sep 05 01:33:28 +0000 2016","truncated":false,"in_reply_to_user_id_str":null,"source":"<a href=\"http://twitter.com/download/iphone\" rel=\"nofollow\">Twitter for iPhone<\/a>","retweet_count":0,"retweeted":false,"geo":null,"in_reply_to_screen_name":null,"is_quote_status":false,"entities":{"urls":[],"hashtags":[],"user_mentions":[],"symbols":[]},"id_str":"772608554834341888","in_reply_to_user_id":null,"favorite_count":0,"id":772608554834341888,"text":"Neville is the most adorable boy in the world","place":{"country_code":"US","country":"United States","contained_within":[],"full_name":"Siloam Springs, AR","bounding_box":{"coordinates":[[[-94.569269,36.15253],[-94.487657,36.15253],[-94.487657,36.2142221],[-94.569269,36.2142221]]],"type":"Polygon"},"place_type":"city","name":"Siloam Springs","attributes":{},"id":"86abfc720d360e37","url":"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/geo/id/86abfc720d360e37.json"},"contributors":null,"lang":"en","user":{"utc_offset":null,"friends_count":258,"profile_image_url_https":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/767399989085483008/Xm0kzU-V_normal.jpg","listed_count":5,"profile_background_image_url":"http://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","default_profile_image":false,"favourites_count":13032,"description":"Jesus. Dreams. World Domination Schemes.","created_at":"Wed Feb 26 23:03:16 +0000 2014","is_translator":false,"profile_background_image_url_https":"https://abs.twimg.com/images/themes/theme1/bg.png","protected":false,"screen_name":"hello_lovelyys","id_str":"2363303335","profile_link_color":"0084B4","is_translation_enabled":false,"id":2363303335,"geo_enabled":true,"profile_background_color":"C0DEED","lang":"en","has_extended_profile":false,"profile_sidebar_border_color":"C0DEED","profile_text_color":"333333","verified":false,"profile_image_url":"http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/767399989085483008/Xm0kzU-V_normal.jpg","time_zone":null,"url":null,"contributors_enabled":false,"profile_background_tile":false,"profile_banner_url":"https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_banners/2363303335/1471797391","entities":{"description":{"urls":[]}},"statuses_count":2760,"follow_request_sent":false,"followers_count":167,"profile_use_background_image":true,"default_profile":true,"following":false,"name":"a stray moonbeam","location":"Strolling through Mordor","profile_sidebar_fill_color":"DDEEF6","notifications":false},"favorited":false}
```

I am definitely getting the raw JSON String but for some reason the createOEmbed method doesn't like it. The stack trace is below.

```
JSONObject["html"] not found.
Relevant discussions can be found on the Internet at:
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=e6edd861 or
    http://www.google.co.jp/search?q=0003ff21
TwitterException{exceptionCode=[e6edd861-0003ff21 7fe5ced0-0f00c8c2], statusCode=-1, message=null, code=-1, retryAfter=-1, rateLimitStatus=null, version=4.0.4}
    at twitter4j.OEmbedJSONImpl.init(OEmbedJSONImpl.java:64)
    at twitter4j.OEmbedJSONImpl.<init>(OEmbedJSONImpl.java:46)
    at twitter4j.TwitterObjectFactory.createOEmbed(TwitterObjectFactory.java:271)
    at com.omnom.connections.TwitterConn.main(TwitterConn.java:53)
Caused by: twitter4j.JSONException: JSONObject["html"] not found.
    at twitter4j.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:391)
    at twitter4j.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:505)
    at twitter4j.OEmbedJSONImpl.init(OEmbedJSONImpl.java:51)
    ... 3 more
```

Thanks for reading!

Answer (score 1):

You must use OEmbedRequest Object before attempting to get html for tweet.

Example:

```
String url = ""

//gets url from id of tweet

OEmbedRequest oEmbedRequest = new OEmbedRequest("tweet id goes here", url);

//embeds into html code to be viewed  

OEmbed embed = twitter.getOEmbed(oEmbedRequest);  

//html result code

System.out.print(embed.getHtml());
```